# Как задать начальную страницу сайта в Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Необходимо, чтобы при переходе на localhost:53060 веб-приложение автоматически перенаправляло пользователя на начальную страницу регистрации

Comment: у вас mvc? или pages? у вас есть home страница или контроллер?

Comment: mvc, контроллер - HomeController, действие - Index

Comment: [Переадресация](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/5.5.php)

Comment: все, я понял. я переопределил маршруты для контроллера и действия через атрибут [Route()], чтобы к ним можно было обращаться по другому имени, через букву нижнего регистра: [Route("[controller]")] и [Route("[action]")]. если обращаться к действию с таким маршрутом через адресную строку браузера, то все работает нормально, но, если через конечные точки, то нет. только что я попробовал немного изменить способ определения маршрута: [Route("{controller=home}")] и [Route("{action=index}")] - и все заработало. Спасибо за помощь в решении проблемы